# Vector problem: given two points $A(2,1)$ and $B(8,3)$

Tags: vectors

Find the coordinates of $C$ so that the distance from $C$ to $AB$ is $2$ and $AC$ and $BC$ are perpendicular.

My first instinct was to draw a circle with $AB$ as the diameter, and I've figured out that there are $4$ possible point $C$'s, but I would appreciate help in how to solve this algebraically.

Answer (score 0):

You're correct in noticing that C represents four points on a circle with diameter AB. I'm going to guess that you have already quantified C in terms of x and y by the equation of that said circle.

Here's a hint: You have three points of a right triangle - A, B, and C. You know that the diameter (base) is $2\sqrt{10}$ and the altitude (height) is $2$. So that means that the area of triangle ABC is $2\sqrt{10}$, no?

For a general polygon, you can use a procedure known as the Shoelace Theorem (you should Google this) to relate the area and vertex points.

In our case, since this is just a three-sided polynomial, the formula works out nicely.

Given vertex $(x_1, y_1), (x_2, y_2), (x_3, y_3)$, then the area of the triangle is given by $|\frac{x_1(y_2-y_3)+x_2(y_3-y_1)+x_3(y_1-y_2)}{2}|$.